# C++ remove matching words from string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, turbo-c++

I am trying to remove certain words (which are in string array) from sentence which is in string.

Here I want to remove strings present in array `tab` from string `s`. So far i am able to break the string but not sure how to check if the specific string present in array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::string s("Somewhere down the road");
std::string tab[2]={"The","the","THE"};

std::string::size_type prev_pos = 0, pos = 0;
while( (pos = s.find(' ', pos)) != std::string::npos )
    {
    std::string substring( s.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos) );
    std::cout << substring << '\n';
    prev_pos = ++pos;
    }
std::string substring( s.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos) );
std::cout << substring << '\n';
}
```

can anyone help here ?

Comment: By "not sure how" do you mean: 1) I can't figure out the algorithm, in which case this has nothing to do with C++, or 2) I know the algorithm, but I'm not sure how some part of it would be translated into C++, in which case you should edit your question, describe your proposed algorithm, and explain what part of it you are having problems translating into C++.

Comment: **Even with Turbo c++:** The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Change std::string tab[2] to std::string tab[3]

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
int main()
{
    std::string s("Somewhere down the road");
    std::string tab[3] = { "The", "the", "THE" };

    std::string::size_type prev_pos = 0, pos = 0;
    std::stack<std::pair<int,int>> erase_pairs;
    while ((pos = s.find(' ', pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string substring(s.substr(prev_pos, pos - prev_pos));
        std::cout << substring << '\n';
        for (auto t = 0; t < 3;t++)
        {
            if (substring == tab[t])
            {
                erase_pairs.push(std::make_pair(prev_pos, pos - prev_pos));
            }
        }
        prev_pos = ++pos;
    }
    for (auto i = 0; i < erase_pairs.size();i++)
    {
        auto what = erase_pairs.top();//I cheated on my homework
        erase_pairs.pop();
        s.erase(what.first, what.second);
    }
    std::string substring(s.substr(prev_pos, pos - prev_pos));//note you also gotta remove the spaces
    std::cout << substring << '\n';
}
```